# Query com resultado null Firebase

Tags: java, android, query, firebase, realtime-database

Olá pessoal estou tendo um problema para realizar query no banco de dados do firebase.

O banco é este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando realizar um busca de todos os restaurantes que tenham o nome Iguatemi, até ai segundo o meu debug, eu estou conseguindo fazer isto de boas.

O problema é que na hora de pegar o dado, está dando retorno como `null`.

Segue imagem do Debug:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:

```
package meals.com.meals.activity.Activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import meals.com.meals.R;
import meals.com.meals.activity.Config.ConfiguracaoFirebase;
import meals.com.meals.activity.modelo.Mesa;
import meals.com.meals.activity.modelo.Restaurante;

import static meals.com.meals.R.array.Restaurante_KFC_Pratos;
import static meals.com.meals.R.array.Restaurante_McDonalds_Pratos;

public class FazerPedido extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView InfoMesa;
    private Spinner SpinnerRestaurante;
    private Spinner SpinnerPratos;
    private Mesa Mesas;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    private Restaurante restaurante;
    private String Local;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fazer_pedido);

        InfoMesa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewInfoMesa);
        SpinnerRestaurante = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerRestaurante);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        final String NFC = bundle.getString("TagNFC");

        Mesa mesas = new Mesa();
       // Restaurante restaurante = new Restaurante()

        reference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReferencia().child("Mesas").child(NFC);


        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Mesa mesas = dataSnapshot.getValue(Mesa.class);
                final String local = mesas.getLocal().toString();
                InfoMesa.setText("Você esta em " + local + " " + "na mesa \n" + NFC);
                // Após ler o NFC ele faz a busca do local

                Query query = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReferencia().child("Restaurante").orderByChild("localRestaurante").equalTo(local);
                // outra referencia porem apontando para restaurante
                query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1) {
                        Restaurante restaurante = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Restaurante.class);
                        final String local = restaurante.getLocalRestaurante();
                        final String nomerest = restaurante.getNome();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Na primeira busca que fiz para retornar o local da mesa só deletando o nó mesa e adicionando de novo a mesas que consegui ter o retorno, tentei realizar o mesmo procedimento porem não houve alteração.

Vou deixar também as duas classes de dos meus objetos para ter uma noção melhor:

**Restaurante.class**

```
public class Restaurante {

private String Nome;
private String LocalRestaurante;
private String ID;
private DatabaseReference reference;

public Restaurante() {

}

public void Salvar(){
    DatabaseReference reference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReferencia();
    reference.child("Restaurante").child(getID()).setValue(this);
}

public String getNome() {
    return Nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    Nome = nome;
}

public String getLocalRestaurante() {
    return LocalRestaurante;
}

public void setLocalRestaurante(String localRestaurante) {
    LocalRestaurante = localRestaurante;
}
@Exclude
public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID() {
    reference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReferencia().child("Restaurante");
    this.ID = reference.push().getKey();
}
}
```

**Mesa.class**

```
public class Mesa {

private String ID;
private String Local;
private String NFC;
private DatabaseReference reference;

public void Salvar(){
    DatabaseReference reference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReferencia();
    reference.child("Mesas").child(getID()).setValue(this);
}


@Exclude
public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID() {
    reference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReferencia().child("Mesas");
    this.ID = reference.push().getKey();

}

public String getLocal() {
    return Local;
}

public void setLocal(String local) {
    Local = local;
}
}
```

Uma coisa que achei bem esquisito também, é o firebase ter deixado eu utilizar a classe mesa sem o seu construtor.

Answer (score 0):

Você esta tentando transformar em um objeto sendo que restaurante é uma lista. Tenta isso:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1) {
    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot1.getChildren()) {
        Restaurante restaurante = postSnapshot.getValue(Restaurante.class);
        final String local = restaurante.getLocalRestaurante();
        final String nomerest = restaurante.getNome();
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu consegui aqui descobri o erro. Vou postar a resposta

Answer (score 0):

O problema de não esta retornando é que estou utlizando uma função errada do firebase para fazer funcionar deve ser utilizado query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() ou query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()

portanto o código ficou deste jeito

```
query query = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReferencia().child("Restaurante").orderByChild("localRestaurante").equalTo(local);

            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    final List<String> areas = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Restaurante restaurante = data.getValue(Restaurante.class);
                        //final String local = restaurante.getLocalRestaurante();
                        //final String nomerest = restaurante.getNome();

                        areas.add(restaurante.getNome().toString());
                    }
                    SpinnerPratos = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerRestaurante);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> areasAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, areas);
                    areasAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
                    SpinnerPratos.setAdapter(areasAdapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: o problema nao é esse, o problema é que voce não estava percorrendo uma lista...

Comment: tanto que se você continuar usando .addChildEventListener e percorrer a lista sera o mesmo resultado.

Comment: @EdsonReis eu tentei utilizar porem não funcionava quando usei single funcionou certinho